# Validation for pair of listboxes

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I have 3 pairs of listboxes.

I would like to make the program proceed only if both listboxes is filled in the pairs.

Its compulsory to fill the first pair which contains `lb1stDebugError` and `lb1stDebug`.

The other pairs can be excluded from the validation if the both `ListBox` within the pair is empty.

The validation is working, but it need to fill up all the listboxes to proceed.

How do I modify the code?

This is my code:

```
If lb1stDebugError.Items.Count = 0 Or lb1stDebug.Items.Count = 0 Then
    pnFCTTesting.Visible = False
    PanelFCTTestingInitialResult.Visible = False
    lblDebugWarningInfo.Visible = True

ElseIf lb2ndDebugError.Items.Count = 0 Or lb2ndDebug.Items.Count = 0 Then
    pnFCTTesting.Visible = False
    PanelFCTTestingInitialResult.Visible = False
    lblDebugWarningInfo.Visible = True

ElseIf lb3rdDebugError.Items.Count = 0 Or lb3rdDebug.Items.Count = 0 Then
    pnFCTTesting.Visible = False
    PanelFCTTestingInitialResult.Visible = False
    lblDebugWarningInfo.Visible = True
End If
```

Appreciate if you guys can help :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this is what you are looking for:

```
Dim pair1Valid = (lb1stDebugError.Items.Count > 0 AndAlso lb1stDebug.Items.Count > 0) _
          OrElse (lb1stDebugError.Items.Count = 0 AndAlso lb1stDebug.Items.Count = 0)
Dim pair2Valid = (lb2ndDebug.Items.Count > 0 AndAlso lb2ndDebug.Items.Count > 0) _
          OrElse (lb2ndDebug.Items.Count = 0 AndAlso lb2ndDebug.Items.Count = 0)
Dim pair3Valid = (lb3rdDebugError.Items.Count > 0 AndAlso lb3rdDebug.Items.Count > 0) _
          OrElse (lb3rdDebugError.Items.Count = 0 AndAlso lb3rdDebug.Items.Count = 0)
Dim allValid = pair1Valid AndAlso pair2Valid AndAlso pair3Valid

pnFCTTesting.Visible = allValid
PanelFCTTestingInitialResult.Visible = allValid
lblDebugWarningInfo.Visible = Not allValid
```